# cat a directories files apending the file name to the row of text and removing the header row?

Tags: text-processing, text

How can I cat a directories files apending the file name to the row of text and removing the header row? So as to only have 1 header row in the all.txt file.

Comment: Are you asking to list file names in a given directory and then redirect them to a text file?

Comment: It should be using `cat`? IMO, cat is useless for editing files.

Comment: What about `ls -al >> ~/all.txt`? Are you wanting the file listing in the directory as I did, or are you wanting to see the contents of each file in the listing?

Comment: I have 225 files of text, each with 2 lines of text a header row and the numerical data. The file name that each set of text is from is what I want to add in a first column on the row with the data. I also want to remove/(not copy) the header row from all but the very first. Thus giving me only one header row at the very top.

Comment: are you looking for `pr *`?

Comment: GNU: `sed -sn '2{F;p}' *|paste -sd'\t\n'`

Answer (score 1):

> I have 225 files of text, each with 2 lines of text a header row and
>   the numerical data. The file name that each set of text is from is
>   what I want to add in a first column on the row with the data. I also
>   want to remove/(not copy) the header row from all but the very first.
>   Thus giving me only one header row at the very top.

If I understood correctly you want the following:

```
for file in *.txt; do echo "$file" $(tail -n1 $file) >> output.txt; done
```

Then edit output.txt to create the header whatever you like.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat a.txt
HEADER
a
b
c
$ cat b.txt
HEADER
1
2
3
$ awk 'NR==1 {print; next} FNR==1 {next} {print FILENAME, $0}' *.txt > all.txt
$ cat all.txt
HEADER
a.txt a
a.txt b
a.txt c
b.txt 1
b.txt 2
b.txt 3
```

Answer (score 1):

Using awk, use the `NR` and `FNR` variables to skip all but the first file's header rows. You can prepend the current filename to the remaining lines by accessing the built-in `FILENAME` variable. For example if there are two header rows in each file, then

```
awk 'NR<3; FNR>2 {print FILENAME,$0}' *.txt > all.txt
```